# tf_conversions replacement in tf2

Tags: ros, tf-conversions, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I understand that now tf is depreciated and the tf packages lib actually runs off tf2. I like to know if the tf_conversions package has any equivalent in tf2? I am trying to build a package which was built for fuerte and uses
TransformTFToEigen
Currently i am given
TransformTFToEigen is not a member of tf
error

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156866/tf_conversions-replacement-in-tf2/) by [zenifed](https://answers.ros.org/users/5788/zenifed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2014-04-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a generic way to convert messages in tf2.  Tutorials are here: http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Migration/DataConversions#preview

Right now there are implementations for kdl, bullet, and geometry_msgs. A contribution of a tf2_eigen package would be appreciated. It would require the equivalent header file to this one for bullet https://github.com/ros/geometry_experimental/blob/indigo-devel/tf2_bullet/include/tf2_bullet/tf2_bullet.h

implementing methods toMsg, fromMsg and doTransform

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0